# undefined method `profile' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having an error "**undefined method `profile' for nil:NilClass**" in my edit view. When I am updating my Profile record and redirecting to the edit page if there is an error, I hit a problem rendering the edit view. Here is the code in my Profiles controller:

```
def edit
    @usermodel = current_usermodel
    @profile = current_usermodel.profile
    if current_usermodel.stripe_access_token.blank?
        flash.keep[:error]  = "Please, connect your #{view_context.link_to('Stripe Account', usermodel_omniauth_authorize_path(:stripe_connect))} to accept payments".html_safe
    end 
end


def update
    @profile = current_usermodel.profile
    respond_to do |format|
    if @profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
    else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
end
```

And in the views, I have the following form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @usermodel.profile do |f| %>
<%= render "pages/error_display", :target => @usermodel.profile %>
</br>
    <b>Business Info </b>
...
```

**@usermodel** is nil and it seems from the controller that this should not be the case

Comment: You should check why your `current_usermodel` returns `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
@usermodel = current_usermodel
```

to update action too.